# Scanning Multiple Column values to create new Column with True or False Value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-science

I have code below as,

```
df['New_Column'] = df[['On Night Shift?']].apply(lambda x: any(x == 'Yes'), axis = 1)
```

which gives me a True or False value in the new column if the column value of On Night Shift? is Yes, if I want to scan multiple different columns for no, how would I tweak this code?

Something like below code,

```
df['New_Column'] = df[['On Night Shift?']].apply(lambda x: any(x == 'No'), axis = 1)
```

except I want to look if the columns O**n Day Shift?, On Mid Shift, On Weekend Shift?** says no as well then give me True in the new column if all say no

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Number':np.arange(10), 'Day Shift':np.random.choice(['Yes', 'No'], 10),
                  'On Mid Shift':np.random.choice(['Yes', 'No'], 10),
                  'On Weekend Shift':np.random.choice(['Yes', 'No'], 10)})

df['No shifts'] = (df[['Day Shift', 'On Mid Shift', 'On Weekend Shift']] == 'No').all(axis=1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Number Day Shift On Mid Shift On Weekend Shift  No shifts
0       0        No          Yes              Yes      False
1       1        No           No               No       True
2       2       Yes          Yes              Yes      False
3       3       Yes           No              Yes      False
4       4        No           No               No       True
5       5        No          Yes              Yes      False
6       6        No          Yes              Yes      False
7       7        No           No              Yes      False
8       8        No          Yes               No      False
9       9       Yes          Yes              Yes      False
```